# empty params variable in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I've set up a router and some routes, and this works for the most part.  when I load #/contacts/123 (or whatever) the ContactIndexRoute returns an empty params object.    I'm sure this is relatively simple, but I cannot figure out why.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

```
CallMonitor.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('contacts', function(){
        this.resource('contact', {path: '/:contact_id'}, function(){

        })
    });
});

CallMonitor.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return  this.store.find('contact');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, contacts) {
        var socket = CallMonitor.Socket;
        controller.set('socket', socket);
        controller.set('contact', contacts);
    },
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this._super(this, arguments);
        this.render('contacts', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'contacts',
            controller: 'contacts'
        });
    }
});

CallMonitor.ContactIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return  this.store.find('contact', params.contact_id);
    },
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this._super(this, arguments);
        this.render('contact', {
            outlet: 'points',
            into: 'contacts',
            controller: 'contactsIndex'
        })
    },
    setupController: function(controller, contact) {
        controller.set('contact', contact);
    }
});

CallMonitor.ContactsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        getPoints: function(data){
            this.transitionToRoute('contact', data.id);
            console.log('the data is' + data );
        }
    },

    socketDidChange: function(){
        var socket = this.get('socket'),
            self = this;
        if(socket)
        {
            socket.on('call', function (data) {
                if(data.contactPointId){

                }
                else if (data.contactId)
                {
                    var contactToUpdate = self.contact.filter(function(item) {
                        return item.id == data.contactId;
                    });
                    if(contactToUpdate.length)
                    {
                        contactToUpdate[0].reload();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // reload all the contacts
                        var contactPromise = self.contact.store.find('contact');
                        contactPromise.then(function(data){
                            self.set('contact', data);
                        }, undefined);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }.observes('socket')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Params are only passed to route which defines the slug.  Meaning if you define a slug on the resource it only exists on the resource, and not its routes.  If it's defined on a route under a resource it only lives on that route.

```
CallMonitor.ContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return  this.store.find('contact', params.contact_id);
    },
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this._super(this, arguments);
        this.render('contact', {
            outlet: 'points',
            into: 'contacts',
            controller: 'contactsIndex'
        })
    },
    setupController: function(controller, contact) {
        controller.set('contact', contact);
    }
});
```